# How to build app through phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have developed one small online game by using phonegap(CSS, HTML, JS and Plugins). How can I build the app with my own plugin which I had made to call the service methods on the server? I have made a multiplayer game app which needs to consume the java webservice on the server side. For this I have made my custom plugins to consume the webservice methods. Its working locally when I am trying to run through eclipse but its not working when I am building my project on the phonegap build server. 
Please help as got stuck due to this in the last step.

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap Build, you will need to submit the plugin for review and it will then be made publicly available for anyone to use. See documentation [here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-contributing). Your other option is to build locally, (cordova, not phonegap build) and you can then keep your plugin private.

Comment: Phonegap build allows you to upload your .zip and they build the app for you on their servers. Cordova allows you to host the build service on your own machine. See here for more info: http://phonegap.com/install/

Comment: Yes I uploaded only asset folder but we have plugins in the src folder then how they will get connect to app??

Comment: Why do you not want to build locally?